# Why my dropdown option doesn't work, I use simple css

Tags: html, css

I'm newly learning web design. I'm trying to create e drop-down but my code doesn't working.
My code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When the mouse will hover the p Tag, the drop down will show. But it doesn't work. Is there any special roles for make it working?

Answer (score 0):

The `dropdown-content div` need to be a **child** of `dropdown div`.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 12px 16px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Mouse over me</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

The second option is changing the CSS code without modifying the HTML code. This can be done by changing the child selector to sibling selector as below:

```
.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 12px 16px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Mouse over me</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to make it working without child div. Is it possible? If possible then what will the css code?

Comment: @Leaners Please see the second option which works with a sibling div. CSS selector has been changed from child selector to sibling selector. See [w3schools CSS selector tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more details.